# Transformation of a uniform distribution in order to get a random variable distributed like Y.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

$f(y)=\begin{cases} \frac{b}{y^2}, & y\ge b,\\ 0, & \mbox{elsewhere}\end{cases}$.

is a bona fide probability density function for a random variable, $Y$. Assuming $b$ is a known
constant and $U$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, 1)$, transform $U$ to obtain a random variable with the same distribution as $Y$.

I have no clue how to get started on this question. Could anyone helps me get started on this question or give some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target distribution is characterized by the fact that any random variable $X$ with this distribution is such that, for every $x\geqslant b$,
$$
P(X\geqslant x)=\int_x^\infty f=\int_x^\infty \frac{b}{y^2}\,\mathrm dy=\frac{b}x.
$$
On the other hand, if $Y=\dfrac{b}U$ with $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$, then for every $y\geqslant b$,
$$
P(Y\geqslant y)=P\left(U\leqslant \frac{b}y\right)=\frac{b}y.
$$
Ergo.

Comment: you mean $y^2$?

Comment: Do I? Really? Where?

Comment: your y... I mean I do not quite get your logic here...Also, I am confused by what the question really wants us to do. Could you let me know what this question wants in term of the actual function.

Comment: Ach so... you do not understand the question. Which part of `Assuming b is a known constant and U has a uniform distribution on the interval (0,1), transform U to obtain a random variable with the same distribution as Y.` is unclear?

Comment: "transform U to obtain a random variable with the same distribution as Y" what are we looking for in terms of math symbols?

Comment: Find a function G such that G(U) has the same distribution as Y.

Comment: "Reserve"? What is "reserve"? (You know, you really have to be more precise if you want to be understood...)

Comment: how do you you determine $P(Y \geq y)$ but not $P(Y \leq y)$?

Comment: The proof I explain computes $P(Y\geqslant y)$. One can deduce from it the value of $P(Y\leqslant y)$ since $P(Y\leqslant y)=1-P(Y\geqslant y)$. (In other words, I still fail to understand your comment. For the last time, please explain in details what you have trouble with, instead of firing haikus at me.)

Comment: I got it...I was thinking $$
P(Y\leqslant y)$$

Comment: $$
P(X\geqslant x)=\int_x^\infty f=\int_x^\infty \frac{b}{y^2}\,\mathrm dy=\frac{b}x.
$$

should your answer be the following
$$
P(X\geqslant x)=\int_b^t f=\int_b^t \frac{b}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt=1-  \frac{b}{y}.
$$

?

Comment: No it should not. Where did you get the absurd identities in the second displayed formula of your comment?

Comment: $$
P(X\geqslant x)=\int_x^\infty f=\int_x^\infty \frac{b}{y^2}\,\mathrm dy=\frac{b}x.
$$

should your answer be the following
$$
P(X\geqslant x)=\int_b^y f=\int_b^y \frac{b}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt=1-  \frac{b}{y}.
$$? This is what I am thinking because I am thinking about the support $ y \ge b$

Comment: Sorry but you are not answering my query for clarification and I have no idea about the real nature of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $b>0$.

Let $\phi(\alpha) = p \{ y | y \le \alpha \} = \int_{-\infty}^\alpha f(y) dy = \begin{cases} 0, & \alpha <b \\ 1-{b \over \alpha}, & \alpha \ge b\end{cases}$.
Note that the restricted $\phi:[b,\infty) \to [0,1)$ is a bijection, and we have
$\phi^{-1}:[0,1) \to [b,\infty)$ is given by
$\phi^{-1}(y) = { b \over 1-y}$.

Then $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is a random  variable with distribution $\phi$.